# Updating items in a grid with checkbox - ionic 2

Tags: typescript, checkbox, ionic2

I hope you can help me.
I have a grid with many columns and I need to update in my database the selected rows pressing a button.
I can't find any info about this.

This is my code.

```html
<ion-row *ngFor="let errors of eta_allErrorsRS">
          <ion-col class="info-col col-align" col-1>
            ETA
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col class="info-col" col-1>
            <ion-checkbox ng-model="active"></ion-checkbox>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col class="info-col col-align" col-1>
            SLI
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col class="info-col col-align" col-1>
            ODBMS
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col class="info-col col-align" col-1>
            {{errors.vc_codi_iata_pais}}
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col class="info-col col-align" col-2>
            {{errors.nb_oc}} + "/" + {{errors.fech_ins_eta}}
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col class="info-col col-align" col-4>
            {{errors.vc_error_envio_eta}}
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col class="info-col col-align" col-1>
            {{errors.fech_eta}}
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col class="info-col col-footer" col-12>
            <button ion-button class="button-footer" smerrors color="bluedark" (click)="republishConfirm()">Republish</button>
            <button ion-button class="button-footer" smerrors color="bluedark" (click)="RejectConfirm()">Reject</button>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Why can't you just call a function with `(click)` and update your database there?

Comment: I am triying, but I can't save the values of the checkboxes to update the data with the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/checkbox/Checkbox/), you should use ngModel like this:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Pepperoni</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="pepperoni"></ion-checkbox>
    <button (click)="updateDatabaseClicked(errors)">ClickOnMe</button>
  </ion-item>
```

Then in your ts file:

```
updateDatabaseClicked(errors){
   writeIntoDatabase(this.pepperoni);
}
```